# getting error while looping through array in shell

Tags: arrays, shell, unix, ftp

I have written a script to ftp a set of files from my directory , but i am getting an error while trying to loop through an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
HOST='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'   
USER='avio'    
PASSWD='jun'    
FILES[0]=D141203.T024413
FILES[1]=D150101.T012755
FILES[2]=D141203.T024418
echo 'no of files: ' ${#FILES[@]}
ftp -n -v $HOST << EOS
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
for i in "${FILES[@]}" 
do 
get $i
done
bye
EOS
```

here is my o/p :

```
no of files: 3
ftp.sh[10]: i: 0403-009 The specified number is not valid for this command.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop is not executed as a `bash` command; rather, it is passed as a string to the `ftp` command. Instead, use a pipe to feed the output of the command to `ftp`:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
HOST='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'   
USER='avio'    
PASSWD='jun'    
FILES[0]=D141203.T024413
FILES[1]=D150101.T012755
FILES[2]=D141203.T024418
echo 'no of files: ' ${#FILES[@]}
{ echo "ascii"
  echo "user $USER $PASSWD"
  for i in "${FILES[@]}";  do 
     echo "get $i"
  done
  echo "bye"
} | ftp -n -v $HOST
```